# Is there a simple IDE with intellisense for Java Development?

Tags: java, ide

First of all, I want to vent my frustration over Eclipse, which although a very good IDE, is simply unable to run a simple Java Hello World program without first associating it with a project (or am I mistaken about this?). In that regard, I loved JCreator LE, which allows you to just bang out Java code very quickly without worrying about creating a project and all that unnecessary stuff for small scale work.

At the same time, I miss some of the intellisense features that Eclipse has. So my question is, is there an IDE that has intellisense and does not require me to associate a Java source file with a project in order to run it. I hope you guys help me out because it is really frustrating to create projects for simple Java programs. Thanks.

Before you downvote - Please note that I read the following on programmers.stackexchange.com
"programming tools (ask on Stack Overflow instead)"
Please see this - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes or close requests. I think this is a great question.

Comment: This question comes up repeatedly here. Peruse the list of related questions to the right.

Comment: just create a fun project in eclipse and then create and run classes (with `main`) methods in that project. That way you don't have to create a new project every time and you get all the bells and whistles in eclipse.

Comment: You don't want an IDE--you want a good editor.  There's a big difference between an IDE and an editor.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci , but editors cannot compile and run programs.

Comment: @CodeBlue, there are tons of editors.  Vim and Emacs come to mind right away.  But I'm not a Java guy so I'm not sure which editors have the best support for Java coding.

Comment: it seems they closed question..very bad

Comment: What nonsense is this? Question closed when the stackexchange site itself says that I am supposed to ask it here. I don't get it.

Comment: Is compiling and running by hand less work than creating a project in an IDE?

Comment: @CodeBlue but they can shell out to run the compiler for you and also run the result.

Comment: @talnicolas Perhaps you haven't used something like JCreator LE. It's so convenient. If only it had intellisense. Could you please explain your decision to close this thread?

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci I believe you've made your point. This is not the place for the IDEs-vs.-editors holy war.

Comment: I believe they closed it because at this point you're at the "Let Me Google That For You" stage.  Google "Java Text Editor" and you'll find lots and lots of hits.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci I found nothing on google for this. It isn't simply a matter of googling "Java text editor" , but with the desired features that I am looking for.

Comment: @CodeBlue Also, the association with a project is somewhat important to making IntelliSense/completion work well and quickly - it lets the IDE establish exactly what it should offer for completion and then cache the required data aggressively. If setting up a project is a bother in Eclipse, you could try IntelliJ or Netbeans to see if you prefer their UI. (Back when I used it, Eclipse seemed to focus on flexibility and completeness over usability.)

Comment: see this post with similar question and lot of answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182071/lightweight-java-ide